# File not opening with C++ fstream even with full path

Tags: c++, ifstream

```
    string mapFile;

    cout << "Enter the file name : ";
    cin >> mapFile;

    ifstream mapfh;
    mapfh.open(mapFile.c_str());
    if(mapfh.is_open()) { ... }
    else //if board file did not open properly
    {
        throw;
    }
    mapfh.close();
```

I am compiling with g++ in the command line.  Whenever I put a file input (even with a full path i.e. /User/...etc./file.txt) it throws an error.  I know the input is good, but for whatever reason the open always fails.

Comment: Does the path have any spaces?

Comment: No, I would drag the file from a finder window to ensure it was the right path.

Comment: Add a `cout << mapFile` to verify the correct filename.

Comment: Do you get an error with any valid file on the system? Might it be a permission problem? Are you able to print/get any specific error returned by the ifstream? Tried your code on my GNU/Linux pc and it worked fine.

Comment: May want to print out the state flags (i.e. rdstate()) to see which bits are set.

Comment: It is a valid file, so there shouldn't be a permission problem.  I just get the error returned by my catch from the 'throw' in the else part of my statement.

Comment: First try to open a file, specified right in the text of the program, w/o any interaction with the user. I suspect _problems_ with `cin`. A typical problem when <newline> isn't stripped from console input, but likely it's not the case.

Answer (score 0):

This isn't fully portable, but you'll get a more informed output if you interpret the `errno`,

```
#include <cerrno>
#include <cstring>

...
if(mapfh.is_open()) { ... }
else //if board file did not open properly
{
    std::cout << "error: " << strerror(errno) << std::endl; 
    throw;
}
```

And if your policy is to communicate the errors as exceptions then [use iostreams native support for the exceptions](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ios/exceptions):

```
ifstream mapfh;
mapfh.exceptions(std::ios::failbit);
try {
    mapfh.open(mapFile.c_str());
    ...
    mapfh.close();
} catch (const std::exception& e) {
    std::cout << e.what() << " : " << std::strerror(errno) << std::endl;
}
```